# Why even bother using public member variables?

Tags: oop

I don't understand why we should even need to use public member vars.

Why can't we always set them to private and use getters/setters instead? Being able to use functions where I can do more than access the variable seems to be always better than just accessing the variable directly and then finding out you need to change something later.

When is it prudent to ever use publics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly Subjective.

But assuming my very subjective perspectives on what seems to be good practice...

Sometimes it's considered "prudent" when you are just using the class as a "Data Transfer Object" sometimes known as a "Value Object". The very nature of these is that they are lean, and contain no behavior and only state. If you are unfamiliar with this pattern it basically just groups objects/primitives together into a container and that is its sole function.

Outside of that it seems be accepted practice that public member fields are ill-advised for the reasons you mentioned. Another reason is *access control*. Sometimes consumers should only be able to read a value, and it should only be able to be set locally. Using Getters/Setters allow you to do things like this. (Some languages also let you do some of this through const/read only fields that can be set once at initialization)

Fowler appears to put serialization functionality on the DTO itself, but one school of thought professes behavior shouldn't exist *on the fields* of a DTO/Value Object.
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

Comment: I should also mention **Immutable Objects** are another case where the method approach seem to not be a great approach since state is frozen once the object is built.

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that your classes that have public member variables remain internal (i.e. no visible to other library / executable), it is fine because everything is under your control. Especially when you want to rapidly develop something or quickly port C code to OO languages such as Java, C#, ...

If the classes are visible outside, better encapsulation can be done by getters / setters.

If you use C# as your programming language, you can enjoy using "property". When you change a field to property, you do not need to change any referenced code (except you have used the field with ref / out).

Comment: In general what you said is true, but not always. Properties have very important differences that should be watched when using anything depending on reflection. Serialization is something in particular to be careful with when using Automatically Implemented Properties since the backing fields are auto-generated and not guaranteed to always be the same in regard to underlying names and such. That said these cases are probably usually the exceptions.

Comment: You are right, if you make use of reflection to such classes, you may need to consider to handle properties and / or fields. For the backing fields naming problem, do reflection only to public properties can prevent this.